# how to print a name using .find

Tags: python, find

Location Name

I need Greec to be Greece

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
position = location.find(":")
```

`.find()` returns `-1` when the thing is not found, as is the case with your "GREECE" entry. Your next line,

```
region_split = location[:position]
```

slices the string up to, but not including, that index. Since index `-1` refers to the last character of the string, it takes all but the last character.

---

The easiest solution would be to put in a special case:

```
position = location.find(":")
region_split = location[:position] if position >= 0 else location[:]
```

but a more fun way would be to use a modulo:

```
position = location.find(":") % (len(location) + 1)
region_split = location[:position]
```

which will not affect `position` if `':'` is found (since it would always be less than `len(location)`, but if `':'` is not found, `-1 % len(location) + 1` evaluates to exactly the length of the string `location`, so you capture the whole string anyway with the following slice.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I kept trying if region_split == -1 print('Location Name') and that didnt work